# Error uploading file over a certain size: '"Not enough space" while reading response header from upstream'

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, openresty

I've recently encountered this error while uploading files to my server which are over a certain size.

It is preceded by a warning which happens whether the error is encountered or not (i.e. the warning occurs also for successful smaller file uploads).

I've tested various sizes and have found that file uploads over 800M all fail in this way.

```
2021/10/24 12:31:06 [warn] 1073#0: *3551 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/client_body_temp/0000000007, request: "POST /upload_file.lua HTTP/1.1"

2021/10/24 12:34:16 [error] 1073#0: *3551 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Not enough space" while reading response header from upstream, request: "POST /upload_file.lua HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/lua.socket:"
```

The results of **df -h**

```
Filesystem      Size    Used    Available    Use%    Mounted on
/dev/root       7.0G    1.1G      5.6G         16%     /
devtmpfs      643.9M     20K    643.9M         16%     /
tmpfs         643.9M     20K    643.9M         16%     /
tmpfs           3.9M     44K      3.9M         16%     /
/dev/root       3.9M    976K      8.8M         16%     /
```

**Edit:**

A 707 M upload is consistently successful (i.e. larger than 643.9M), and the temporary buffer file is stored at /usr/local/openresty/nginx/client_body_temp/000000000x

Comment: What happens to uploads that are over 643.9M ?

Comment: A 707M upload is consistently successful.